# Unable to start debugging for C++

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-code

Every time i want to run my c++ code it show unable to debugging and not implemented.
please help to solve my problems
it seems error in launch.jsons /  task.jsons / c_cpp_properties.jsons
please help me to resolve these error . I am new in coding and i am stuck in this from 4 days .

launch.jsons
{

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    

        {
        "name": "(Windows) Launch",
        "type": "cppvsdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "C:\\Users\\Sumit\\Desktop\\vs code Projects\\CPP Projects\\hello_world.cpp",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "C:\\MinGW\\bin",
        "environment": [],
        "console": "externalTerminal"
    }
]
```

}

```
 task.jsons
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "compiler: C:\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe"
        }
    ]
}




c_cpp_properties.jsons

{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "C:\\MinGW\\lib\\gcc\\mingw32\\6.3.0"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "cStandard": "gnu11",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++14",
            "intelliSenseMode": "windows-gcc-x86"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Comment: I believe this is wrong: `"program": "C:\\Users\\Sumit\\Desktop\\vs code Projects\\CPP Projects\\hello_world.cpp",` This should be the executable not the cpp file. Also you should avoid using spaces in paths. It will likely cause you build problems at some point.